# How to make an object fall to the ground?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I'm quite new to Swift and visionOS. I was following this simple [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Ihjfl_6tkKw?si=m8VAHqz2fw1R2jSR&t=1176) where an object is added to the scene and then applied some physics. However, as you can see in the image (using the simulator), the object doesn't fall and stays where I've initially positioned it.

I've checked and my code is pretty much the same as in the tutorial (except of the 3D Object). I've also tried asking ChatGPT/GPT-4 and checking for other tutorials online but nothing seems to give a good clue of what's the issue.

I'm running out of options. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Pretty much this is the code I have but feel free to look at the [repository directly](https://github.com/aajn88/visionos-hello-world/blob/main/OSHelloWorld/ImmersiveView.swift). I've found the [apple 3D model here](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/apple-free-usdz-2d8f54fb626042b695f7c0f1be969d78#download) in case it's important.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 50, depth: 50), materials: [OcclusionMaterial()])
            floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            floor.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(
                massProperties: .default,
                mode: .static
            )
            
            content.add(floor)
            
            if let appleModel = try? await Entity(named: "Apple_Reduced"), let apple = appleModel.children.first?.children.first {
                let scale: Float = 3
                apple.scale = [scale, scale, scale]
                apple.position.y = 0.5
                apple.position.z = -1
                
                apple.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
                apple.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
                
                apple.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(PhysicsBodyComponent(
                    massProperties: .default,
                    material: .generate(staticFriction: 0.8, dynamicFriction: 0.5, restitution: 0.1),
                    mode: .dynamic))
                
                apple.components[PhysicsMotionComponent.self] = .init()
                
                content.add(apple)
            }
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .onChanged { value in
                debugPrint("onChanged")
                value.entity.position = value.convert(value.location3D, from: .local, to: value.entity.parent!)
                value.entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self]?.mode = .kinematic
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                debugPrint("onEnded")
                value.entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self]?.mode = .dynamic
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ImmersiveView()
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
}
```

[image: Apple not falling to the ground]

### When making `apple.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)`

If I make the `generateCollisionShapes` for the apple to be recursive (`apple.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)`) then I can drag and drop but it has a weird behavior in which the apple gets closer when I drag it.

[image: Apple Drag and Drop]

## My dev environment

- MacBook Pro, Apple M2
- Memory 16GB
- macOS Sonoma 14.3
- Xcode 15.3 Beta 2 (also tried 15.2)
- visionOS 1.1 beta 2 (also tried 1.0)

Comment: Oh - forgot to mention. Additionally, the dragGesture doesn't work either unless I do `apple.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)` instead of `false`. It has a weird behavior as well as it seems to get closer every time I drag it

Comment: Andy, sorry about that. I've reverted to the original question. I'll also check your comment on the answer today, sorry I haven't had the chance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the difference between `Entity` and `ModelEntity`.

> the model entity has components for visual appearance (ModelComponent), collision detection (CollisionComponent), and physics simulations (PhysicsBodyComponent and PhysicsMotionComponent).

`Entity` isn't capable of handling all the components you need.

The `ModelEntity` for the file you got from the internet is buried deep inside.

```
▿ 'Meshes' : Entity, children: 1
  ⟐ Transform
  ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
  ▿ 'Sketchfab_model' : Entity, children: 1
    ⟐ Transform
    ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ▿ 'USDRoot' : Entity, children: 1
      ⟐ Transform
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
      ▿ 'export' : Entity, children: 1
        ⟐ Transform
        ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
        ▿ 'Geom' : Entity, children: 1
          ⟐ Transform
          ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
          ▿ 'Node_0' : Entity, children: 1
            ⟐ Transform
            ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
            ▿ 'Node_0' : Entity, children: 1
              ⟐ Transform
              ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
              ▿ 'Node_0' : ModelEntity // <--- HERE
                ⟐ ModelComponent
                ⟐ Transform
                ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
```

So if you replace

```
let apple = appleModel.children.first?.children.first {
```

With

```
let apple = appleModel.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first{
```

I used `print` statements to find it.

```
if let appleModel = try? await Entity(named: "Apple_Reduced"),
    let apple = appleModel.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first?.children.first{
    print(apple)
    print(type(of: apple))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### ISSUE IS FOUND

Antonio, after thorough "investigation" I've found the issue - we are using different models. I'm using `Original` USDZ (as well as the author of your tutorial), however, you're using `Converted` format. These two models have different hierarchies. ModelEntity in your USDZ is deeper in hierarchy than in mine. To find your ModelEntity use:

```
if let appleModel = try? await Entity(named: "Apple_Reduced"), 
            
    let apple = appleModel.findEntity(named: "Node_0")?.children[0].children[0] {  
    print(apple)       // ModelEntity

    // Code here....
}
```

[image]

---

#### M1 cpu, macOS 14.3.1, Xcode 15.3 beta 3, visionOS 1.1 beta 2 simulator

Your code works fine, including gesture. Everything I changed (simplified) is described below. To test a scene, I used `ContentView()` in **App.swift** file and renamed **ImmersiveView** into **ContentView** in ContentView.swift file. Also, in **info.plist** tab I set ***Preferred Default Scene Session Role*** to `Immersive Space Application Session Role` value.

#### Important

Before running a project you should do six things:

1. In Xcode, press <kbd>Command</kbd>–<kbd>Option</kbd>–<kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut to clean your build folder.
2. Go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and delete all the projects here.
3. Go to `Xcode Settings –> Platforms` and delete all previous versions of visionOS.
4. Go to `Simulator Device –> Erase All Content and Settings`.
5. Reset visionOS simulator.
6. Restart computer.

---

[image]

Then run my shared project. Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main struct YourApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 50, depth: 50), 
                                                     materials: [OcclusionMaterial()])
            floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            floor.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(
                massProperties: .default,
                mode: .static
            )
            content.add(floor)
            
            if let appleModel = try? await Entity(named: "Apple_Reduced"), 
               let apple = appleModel.children.first?.children.first {
                print(apple)     // it's ModelEntity

                let scale: Float = 3
                apple.scale = [scale, scale, scale]
                apple.position.y = 0.5
                apple.position.z = -2
                
                apple.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
                apple.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
                
                apple.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(PhysicsBodyComponent(
                    massProperties: .default,
                          material: .generate(staticFriction: 0.8,
                                             dynamicFriction: 0.5,
                                                 restitution: 0.1),
                             mode: .dynamic))
                
                apple.components[PhysicsMotionComponent.self] = .init() 
                content.add(apple)
            }
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .onChanged { value in
                debugPrint("onChanged")
                value.entity.position = value.convert(value.location3D, 
                                         from: .local, 
                                           to: value.entity.parent!)
                value.entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self]?.mode = .kinematic
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                debugPrint("onEnded")
                value.entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self]?.mode = .dynamic
            }
    }
}
```

#### For the sake of the purity of the experiment

[image]

To make sure that the model is not buggy, try the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    let floorPlane = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 10, depth: 10)
    let ball = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.3))
    let shape = ShapeResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.3)
    let physicsResource = PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(
                                            staticFriction: 0.8, 
                                           dynamicFriction: 0.5, 
                                               restitution: 0.1)
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            // FLOOR
            let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: floorPlane,
                               materials: [OcclusionMaterial()])
            floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            floor.physicsBody = .init()
            floor.physicsBody?.mode = .static
            content.add(floor)
            
            // BALL
            ball.position.y = 0.5
            ball.position.z = -2
            ball.components[CollisionComponent.self] = .init(shapes: [shape])
            ball.components[InputTargetComponent.self] = .init()
            ball.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(
                                                   shapes: [shape],
                                                     mass: 0.1,
                                                 material: physicsResource,
                                                     mode: .dynamic
            )
            content.add(ball)
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .onChanged {
                $0.entity.position = $0.convert($0.location3D, from: .local, to: $0.entity.parent!)
                $0.entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self]?.mode = .kinematic
            }
            .onEnded {
                $0.entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self]?.mode = .dynamic
            }
    }
}
```

#### For those who are interested

If I `print(apple)` in console it'll look like this:

```
▿ 'Node_0' : ModelEntity
  ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
  ⟐ Transform
  ⟐ ModelComponent
```