# I've tried to give a physicsBodyComponent to modelEntity, and it is just not sitting on the floor currectly

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

there was simple 6 sided dice before this 12 sided dice as ModelEntity but back then it was working properly for 6 sided dice.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf9C5.jpg)

```
            let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 50, depth: 50), materials: [OcclusionMaterial()])
            floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            floor.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(
                massProperties: .default,
                mode: .static
            )
            
            content.add(floor)
            
            if let diceModel = try? await Entity(named: "d20"),
               let dice = diceModel.children.first?.children.first {
                dice.scale = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
                dice.position.y = 0.5
                dice.position.z = -1
                
                dice.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                dice.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
                
                dice.components.set(ImageBasedLightReceiverComponent(imageBasedLight: dice))
                dice.components.set(GroundingShadowComponent(castsShadow: true))
                
                dice.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(PhysicsBodyComponent(
                    massProperties: .default,
                    material: .generate(staticFriction: 0.8, dynamicFriction: 0.5, restitution: 0.1),
                    mode: .dynamic
                ))
                
                dice.components[PhysicsBodyComponent]
                
                
                dice.components[PhysicsMotionComponent.self] = .init()
                
                content.add(dice)
            }
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the child is a ModelEntity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974456/how-to-make-an-object-fall-to-the-ground/78014189#78014189

Comment: Thanks for your reply
yes thats all correct
But as of i observed it , i think it has some problem with its Physics body component and thats why shape is not colliding properly with the floor.